# How do I predict x values with confidence intervals from non-linear polynomial fit in R?

Tags: r, prediction, curve-fitting, polynomial

I have the following data.frame:

```
structure(list(days = c(11, 23, 31, 6, 9, 54, 61, 179, 195, 209, 
223, 42, 56, 106, 162, 225, 96, 161, 89, 154, 218, 98, 159, 224, 
104, 155, 246, 99, 159, 225, 91, 152, 210, 118, 166, 228, 98, 
154, 213, 100, 156, 215, 102, 154, 87, 157, 215, 93, 163, 93, 
163, 221, 109, 162, 226, 103, 168, 95, 160, 216, 102, 167, 223, 
98, 167, 95, 155, 212, 107, 165, 221, 95, 173, 110, 171, 101, 
175, 96, 173, 97, 172, 108, 184, 93, 174, 183, 15, 31, 61, 177, 
205, 61, 171, 100, 178, 103, 188, 92, 185, 102, 185, 102, 185, 
186, 197, 213, 234, 177, 191, 208, 55, 83, 88, 201, 218, 80, 
183, 89, 186, 97, 198, 122, 210, 91, 217, 101, 220, 2, 5, 7, 
9, 12, 13, 14, 20, 25, 27, 29, 30, 33, 40, 45, 57, 88, 92, 92, 
92, 93, 94, 94, 95, 96, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 100, 
102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 
106, 107, 109, 109, 109, 117, 119, 134, 142, 156, 167, 185, 206, 
216, 226), inhib = c(83.57963875, 93.24028462, 94.11379987, 22.1713538260301, 
55.12658228, 65.688842325825, 59.4552121529597, 31.6372343609698, 
32.2840690978887, 30.4054054054054, 21.0394914491449, 31.5132605304212, 
21.9941348973607, 65.1536119568226, 47.7383863080685, 41.3663663663664, 
55.7708275671187, 52.8117359413203, 55.8815388873512, 26.1002444987775, 
21.4764719715215, 61.4724605590922, 33.3129584352078, 25.9009009009009, 
27.9001468428781, 33.0073349633252, 15.9159159159159, 22.7864583333333, 
30.9902200488998, 26.3663190643389, 81.640625, 70.5378973105135, 
40.990990990991, 85.9275575134606, 82.2738386308068, 76.4264264264264, 
47.1120900636319, 44.8044009779951, 32.1321321321321, 61.2090063631914, 
72.3105134474328, 76.5765765765766, 85.7562408223201, 90.3422982885086, 
67.5339053418212, 38.4474327628362, 34.2342342342342, 63.8804317741489, 
48.2273838630807, 88.34763354553, 74.2053789731051, 65.3903903903904, 
75.9911894273128, 93.6430317848411, 93.7687687687688, 59.6734016053141, 
48.6552567237164, 69.6374204262386, 62.2860635696821, 35.960960960961, 
30.722391364517, 21.6381418092909, 13.4384384384384, 63.4099086631608, 
65.4645476772616, 92.0949583945179, 94.6210268948655, 89.2642642642643, 
71.0474791972589, 81.1735941320293, 72.0720720720721, 0.130208333333337, 
10.2078239608802, 94.3220753793441, 95.4767726161369, 93.2189316357598, 
88.2029339853301, 82.4245779130916, 91.6259168704157, 92.1118184334348, 
85.880195599022, 89.9529476889012, 94.8655256723716, 53.9994464433988, 
51.7114914425428, 28.947972972973, 78.59879584, 80.94936709, 
58.374733853797, 29.691709069141, 16.5451055662188, 89.1767210787793, 
70.6375336725531, 84.9155826183227, 79.7011559063998, 76.1140326598395, 
77.5021144629264, 96.2358151120952, 96.3349309275444, 74.0381954054802, 
61.1502678319707, 81.2897868807085, 47.6740907809416, 22.568093385214, 
12.4998648648649, 9.90403071017274, 9.35030558055806, 63.1846752469321, 
63.1633783783784, 62.8790786948177, 84.719481251762, 67.3423423423423, 
91.3645170218655, 67.7177177177177, 74.024024024024, 83.8361472460559, 
88.963963963964, 67.2017713811237, 53.6786786786787, 87.9878217547744, 
66.6666666666667, 65.6877141458639, 76.9599595094645, 56.4904511486299, 
35.6606606606607, 35.8296622613803, 22.1471471471472, 18.52764094, 
19.81390257, 83.16455696, 41.0398953564421, 26.92939245, 62.5, 
89.13519431, 78.9556962, 88.7835186396338, 44.19813903, 63.0477436232832, 
24.11392405, 84.7128712871287, 76.22629169, 39.1304347826087, 
61.5054602184087, 11.0677083333333, 66.5375034597288, 48.6853030722391, 
77.4702463326875, 71.7132576805978, 24.4357638888889, 57.2482638888889, 
81.5665651812898, 81.7603099916967, 55.9895833333333, 60.1162468862441, 
52.4229074889868, 47.65625, 86.4378632715195, 0, 53.7689672050906, 
64.7107666758926, 65.0982562967063, 70.9006363191385, 56.1429270680372, 
78.5773595350125, 40.9355106559646, 79.4353722668143, 41.3607440039158, 
26.5051395007342, 16.054821341165, 38.4238864415076, 10.2131192914476, 
69.652471855115, 9.5692608908468, 12.7170138888889, 88.569056185995, 
68.6686963742042, 86.1967694566814, 43.4818710213119, 92.9975089952948, 
0, 4.01370533529125, 95.83956899132, 36.8581907090465, 76.5892420537897, 
15.9775675675676, 51.1136171412461, 82.4252019796574, 40.3903903903904, 
57.957957957958)), row.names = c(NA, -189L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I fit a second degree polynomial model to the data:

```
fit2 <- lm(inhib ~poly(days,2), data = dat)
```

and it looks like this in ggplot:

```
  ggplot(dat, aes(days, inhib))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~poly(x,2))+ 
  ylim(c(0,100))+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 20)
```

[image]

What I would like to do is predict the x(days) at which the model predicts y(inhib) = 20  with confidence intervals in days.

In other words the x value where the blue line intercepts the black line, with confidence intervals in terms of x.

Using the predict function I can put in a few values and eventually get to:

```
>predict(fit2, data.frame(days = 302), interval = 'confidence')

      fit       lwr      upr
>1 20.33934 -7.256038 47.93471
```

but this is telling me that at y=20.33934 (CI -7.25 to 47.93) at x = 302 days,

What I want to be able to predict from the model is at y=20 x = ?days (CI ?lower to ?upper)

I am sure there is something basic I am missing here...

Comment: I don't follow your question: could you explain what you think is wrong with your calculation?  BTW, this is an example of a *fiducial interval* obtained through *inverse regression.*  For a discussion (in the simpler context of simple regression) see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/206682/919.  Because you are fitting a quadratic, you won't obtain a simple interval as the solution, though.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. The problem with calculation is 2 fold. 1) I arbritarily put in a bunch of x values (days) untill I got a predicted y value of 20. Which is ok but I would like to use R to somehow get an exact value for the predicted x value at y=20. 2) I would then like the upper and lower CI of the model in terms of this predicted x. So simplistically the x (days) values where the grey shaded Confidence Intervals around the blue modelled line on the graph cross the y = 20. At the moment using predict instead I am getting CI in terms of y values... How this makes more sense?

Comment: A little.  It sounds like you are trying to find the (up to) *four* places where the upper and lower confidence curves intersect a line.  That's a little tricky because of the multiple solutions as well as the prospect that fewer than four exist, but it's still just a matter of finding roots of a univariate function.  In `R` you could use `uniroot` effectively after first identifying intervals where you know a root must exist.

Comment: Thanks again. Sounds a little outside my understating but will give it a go. I would like the 95% confidence Intervals of that makes it any easier. So should only be 2 places? One upper and one lower?

Comment: In your example, the fitted curve will intersect $y=20$ in two locations: one near $x=300$ and the other near $-200$ (I'm eyeballing the curve, not computing anything). In the first case the interval is likely to go from around $250$ up to $+\infty.$  In the second place it will go from around $-150$ down to $-\infty.$  Together these form a *fiducial region* for $x.$  With some caution you could interpret the first interval as sort of a confidence interval for the upper intersection.

Comment: Ah I get the reasoning now. Just trying to get my head around the terminology and then how to actually implement it in R. Thanks for your help, has been enlightening but think this may be a step too far for me. I thought it would be a simple almost "inverse" predict function to predict x from y with CI rathe than y from x as the formula I thought would be as simple as solving the algebra...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for similar answers, I managed to figure out part of the solution. To find out the x value at y=20 I used:

ypredict <- 20

```
 fun <- function(x1, y1, mod) {
    predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(days=x1)) - y1
    }    
                
(xpred <- sapply(ypredict, function(z) uniroot(fun, interval=c(0, 500), mod=fit2, y1=z)$root))
        
> [1] 302.8676
```

WARNING: I was also warned by a mathematician colleague that using quadratic functions for prediction (extrapolation beyond data specifically) is not advised as polynomial functions, naturally, tend to +/- infinity

Comment: +1 for this answer, especially for the warning.  I think that's the best answer:  It's dangerous to extrapolate beyond the range of observed data.  Especially considering the data presented here, with so much variability, one would have little confidence that the fitted model would be reliably applicable outside the observed range.